# Python: Creating a multicolumn series with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to create a multicolumn series using pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
StartTime = '2015-10-01'
EndTime = '2016-01-01'
step = '1min'

Time= pd.date_range(StartTime,EndTime,freq=step)
Value1 = np.random.choice(range(0,100),len(Time))
Value2 = np.random.choice(range(0,100),len(Time))
Value3 = np.random.choice(range(0,100),len(Time))
#Time series of one variable
TimeSeries = pd.Series(Time,Value1)
```

What I want is that every time point to have 3 variables. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
 TimeSeries = pd.Series(Time,Value1,Value2,Value3)
```

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this would work:

```
>>> TimeSeries = pd.Series(tuple(zip(*(Value1, Value2, Value3))), index=Time)
>>> TimeSeries.head()
2015-10-01 00:00:00    (71, 58, 69)
2015-10-01 00:01:00     (59, 1, 94)
2015-10-01 00:02:00     (50, 65, 6)
2015-10-01 00:03:00     (16, 50, 7)
2015-10-01 00:04:00    (20, 36, 41)
Freq: T, dtype: object
```

it would be better to use data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': Value1, 'Value2': Value2, 'Value3':Value3}, index=Time)
>>> df.head()
                     Value1  Value2  Value3
2015-10-01 00:00:00      71      58      69
2015-10-01 00:01:00      59       1      94
2015-10-01 00:02:00      50      65       6
2015-10-01 00:03:00      16      50       7
2015-10-01 00:04:00      20      36      41
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. Yea, it seems that your second answer is more easy for later use of the data.

Comment: Yes, that is what data frames are made for.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris Looks like you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) ;).

Comment: Sorry for not upvoting earlier. I guess I was over-excited to go through my task :)